# Connect to a SQL Server database in WPF C# (.exe) application from any PC

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, wpf

Current connection string:

```
Data Source=DESKTOP-2LESKTC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test_database;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=5
```

I am building an application that is using a SQL Server database and is working fine on my PC when I run the `.exe` file of the WPF / C# application; but my problem is: how can I make the connection string (datasource) of SQL Server generic that my `.exe` file will automatically detect it whenever its installed on any new client PC?

I will add SQL Server dependencies but data source remains same in my code which is my current PC, how to change it in such a way that it can vary automatically when application is deployed?

Comment: it's unclear, you mean like `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` or `.\SQLEXPRESS` ?

Comment: localhost\sqlexpress

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to accomplish that goal, however the most common is to make use of the [ConfigurationManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Configuration_ConfigurationManager_ConnectionStrings) that reads from an App.Config file that contains your connection string. You can then add App.config transformations for you different environments that contain connection strings specific to those environments.